# How to check if objects in an array of objects all have specific structure and are not a null?

Tags: javascript, angular

I receive an array of objects from the server. But my app breaks because some objects do not have a structure just a null value and my logic depends on checking against certain object keys to do one thing or another. Here is an example of an array that i receive:

```
[{
  clienTnames: {
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Jackson'
  }
}, {
  clienTnames: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Johnson'
  }
}, {
  clienTnames: null
}]
```

I would like to check if any objects arrive as null and if they do switch them to empty object with all the proper keys just with no value. So if I receive clienTnames: null; I would like to automatically change it to clienTnames : {firstName: ' ', lastName: ' '}

Answer (score 1):

Just use a map function:

```
names = names.map(name => {
  return name.clienTnames
    ? name.clienTnames
    : { clienTnames: { firstName: '', lastName: '' } }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `defaultObj` with all the default properties. Then loop through the array and update items which have `clienTnames` property set to null

```js
let array = [{clienTnames:{firstName:'Jack',lastName:'Jackson'}},{clienTnames:{firstName:'John',lastName:'Johnson'}},{clienTnames:null}]

const defaultObj = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: ''
}

array.forEach(a => {
  if(!a.clienTnames) 
    a.clienTnames = { ...defaultObj }
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Don't use a `defaultObj` since all the array elements will point to the same object.

Comment: @ritaj It won't. It's creating a clone using the spread syntax every loop

Comment: Sorry I have commented on the wrong answer. Check the one bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = [{ clienTnames: { firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Jackson' } }, { clienTnames: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Johnson' } }, { clienTnames: null }];

let output = [];

output = data.map(element => {
    if (element.clienTnames) {
        return element;
    } else {
        return { clienTnames: { firstName: '', lastName: '' } };
    }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [{
  clienTnames: {
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Jackson'
  }
}, {
  clienTnames: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Johnson'
  }
}, {
  clienTnames: null
}];

let targetArray;

targetArray = array.map((item) => {
  if(!item.clienTnames) {
    return { clienTnames: { firstName: '', lastName: '' } }
  }

  return item;
})
```

Comment: Don't use a `defaultObj` since all the array elements will point to the same object.

Comment: What will happen?

Comment: If you change one of the elements, the other will change as well.